# CURLOPT_PUT vs CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, api, curl, put

When I sent the PUT request API via curl to the REST, I found strange behavior. If you set the parameter ***curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true)***, then queries, in which CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is not empty, then the query execution lasts 1.5 minutes (as if it depends on some timeout). And if the same request is sent with the parameter ***curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT")***, then the query execution lasts about 1 second, as it should be. Can someone explain the fundamental difference between these parameters?

Example code:

```
$data = http_build_query(array("enable"=> 1));

if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, BASE_URL .'users/2');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);    
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true); // execution time 1.5 min
    //curl_setopt ($ curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); - execution time 1 sec
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $out = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    curl_close($curl);      
}
```

Comment: When `CURLOPT_PUT` is `true`, then it is expecting to put a file and the same file MUST be set with `CURLOPT_INFILE` and `CURLOPT_INFILESIZE`. When you use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` it doesn't expect file to PUT.

Comment: @DileepKumar It turns out that if I do not send a file to the PATH request, but send the object, then I must always use CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST?

Comment: Yes, I think so, because if you set `CURLOPT_PUT` then you need to set file using `CURLOPT_INFILE` and `CURLOPT_INFILESIZE`.

Comment: @DileepKumar Great thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), It says that when you set `CURLOPT_PUT` to `true`then the file to `PUT` must be set with `CURLOPT_INFILE` and `CURLOPT_INFILESIZE` (In your case you are not setting the file).

Setting `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to `PUT` method is not expecting the file which is the main difference between `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` and `CURLOPT_PUT`.