# CURL put not sending data

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to create a curl PUT request. However, for some reason the json data doesn't get send to the api server.

```php
 public function sendRequest($endpoint, $method, $params = [], $data = null)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        $url = $this->host . "/" . $endpoint . "?" . http_build_query($params);
        $data = array(
            'ItemCode' => '3505180',
            'SearchCode' => '123456',
        );
        $data_string = json_encode($data);
        switch ($method) {
            case "GET":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
                break;
            case "POST":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                if ($data) {
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                }
                break;
            case "PUT":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
                
                if ($data) {
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:51290');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'X-ApiKey: ' . $this->apiKey,
            'administration: ' . $this->administration,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ));

        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        if(curl_errno($curl))
        {
            $result = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
        }
        curl_close($curl);


        return $result;
```

This is how I use the sendRequest function:

```php
public function updateItem($item)
    {

        $this->sendRequest("api/Item", "PUT", [], "some json data should go here");

    }
```

If I look up the request in Fiddler, the JSON body or raw body is empty. This is the raw data:

```
PUT http://appsrv:889/api/Item HTTP/1.1
Host: appsrv:889
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
X-ApiKey: xxxxx
administration: 002
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 44
Expect: 100-continue
```

I get the following as result:

```
HTTP/1.1 408 Request body incomplete
Date: Wed, 17 Aug 2022 07:18:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 09:18:01.979

The request body did not contain the specified number of bytes. Got 0, expected 44
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Content Length = 3, thats from your `aaa` value, try to `var_dump` your `$data` and see whats in there first

Comment: Shouldn't you be sending `$data_string` rather than `$data`? Otherwise, why create that variable?

Comment: And you have `'Content-Type: application/json'` for `aaa`.

Comment: It was for testing only. If I put $data_string in the PUT method, I get a Content-Lenght of 44. However it doesn't return anything and in Fiddler no JSON shows up. Ik get the following error:
The request body did not contain the specified number of bytes. Got 0, expected 44

Comment: I changed the question with the correct code and raw output.

Comment: isn't your script expecting the posted fields in the format ItemCode=12345&SeachCode=abc ?

Comment: Hi @IvoP, no it's not. In Insomnia, a REST API client I can set the JSON content with same headers and it will work.

Comment: what if you replace your curlopt_put line with : curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

Comment: @IvoP That did the trick! It works, thank you a lot! :-) Why shouldn't it work with CURLOPT_PUT with a value of 1 tho?

Comment: That's because curlopt_put expects a file to be uploaded. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918152/curlopt-put-vs-curlopt-postfields