# PHP CURLOPT_PUT - How send parameters?

Tags: php, curl

how can I send parameters and file together? File is OK, but parameters is not passed.

```
$file_path_str = some file
$url = API url
$data = array("id"=>3);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);

$fh_res = fopen($file_path_str, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh_res);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_path_str));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

fclose($fh_res);
```

Postman:

[image]

Sample code C#

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271140/curl-and-php-how-can-i-pass-a-json-through-curl-by-put-post-get, you should likely find your answer there

Comment: Well firstly, what does the remote API expect? If it is allowing a file upload, I highly doubt it expects a JSON object alongside it? More likely a multipart/form-data request, surely? Start by consulting the documentation of the remote API for the expected upload format. Then you may find that things like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+curl+send+multipart+request+with+file+data) start to be helpful

Comment: @JarmoT Unlikely - I would be surprised if the API expected JSON and file data together. It's not impossible, but very unusual, and thoroughly managles any usage of standard content-types. But before making too many assumptions, the OP should inform us of the specification of this endpoint of the API they are trying to use, which is missing from the question.

Comment: Use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');`

Comment: Regarding the above comment from Wakil Ahmed, there is more info at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44918714/5947043

Comment: I add screenshots (test in Postman and sample source code C#)

Comment: Thanks. Did you try using Postman to auto-generate the PHP cURL code for you, based on the parameters of the Postman request? It usually does a pretty good job. And did you try Wakil's suggestion? What was the outcome?

Comment: Also `curl_file_create()` is usually used to set file uploads using PHP curl. Have you tried using that?

Answer (score 0):

A single common way to send both a file and data in a cURL request is to use the `multipart/form-data` content type, which is typically used for file  uploads. You can use the curl_setopt function to set the necessary options.

```
$file_path_str = 'somefile.txt'; // Replace with the actual file path
$url = 'API URL';
$data = array("id" => 3);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // Use POST method for sending data and file

// Create a multipart/form-data request
$post_fields = array(
'file' => curl_file_create($file_path_str), // Add the file to the request
'data' => json_encode($data) // Add your additional data
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Process the response as needed
```

Comment: Yes, although then putting JSON data within a form-data parameter is a bit of a dirty hack.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Problem 1) Function curl_file_create() is not supported (PHP 5.3)
Problem 2) Method must be PUT (2N SIP Speaker)

Comment: Solution  1). The curl_file_create() function is not available in PHP 5.3. To work around this, you can use the @ symbol to create a file upload in PHP 5.3
Solution 2).  If you need to use the PUT method instead of POST, you can modify the code accordingly.